# Share image to WhatsApp directly using url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, url-scheme, whatsapi

I want to integrate `WhatsApp` sharing in my app but I don't want to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Is there any way to share image using `url scheme` ? like we share text using url scheme using following code below

```
var whatsappURL:NSURL?= NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL)) {    
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it.

Firstly, the Whatapps only support send text via `URLScheme`. Secondly, how you can put your image in the urlString? Convert it to base64string?

You can only send image by using [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: actually i did same thing with instagram  and i shared image using url scheme

here is  my code for instagram (i am posting code in next comment because of character limit)

Comment: `
let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app") PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: self.image)
                let assetID = request.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier ?? ""
                let shareURL = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + assetID            
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {
                    if let urlForRedirect = NSURL(string: shareURL) {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlForRedirect as URL)
                        }
 `